# How to apply conditional fomatting for a MAX value to a range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table that is five cells wide by twenty high with a sum function at the end (e.g. cel A20). I want to highlight the column that results in the highest SUM. How do I use conditional formatting with the formula condition IF A20=MAX(A20:E20) THEN Highlight A1:A20?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That works pretty much exactly as you noted:

1. Highlight A1:E20
2. Apply CF formula that is CUSTOM, this is a slight variation to your formula:
   =A$20=MAX($A$20:$E$20)
   [image]
3. Format ... Yellow
4. And the result is the MAX column will highlight
   [image]